# In .net maui, I cannot stop the android service via broadcastreceiver

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

Service code:

```
namespace WakeUp.Platforms.Android
{
    [Service]
    internal class LocationService : Service
    {
        private readonly CancellationTokenSource token;
        private readonly string ChannelId = "WakeUpService";
        private readonly int NotificationId = 1;
        private readonly string NotificationChannelName = "WakeUp!";

        private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        private Timer timer;
        public string Title { get; private set; }
        public string Description { get; private set; }


        public LocationService()
        {
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            timer = new Timer(3000);
            timer.Elapsed += VibrateTimer;

            
        }

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        private void CreateNotificationChannel(NotificationManager manager)
        {
            #pragma warning disable CA1416
            var serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(ChannelId, NotificationChannelName, NotificationImportance.Default);
            manager.CreateNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
            #pragma warning restore CA1416
        }
        public void StartForegroundService()
        {
            var Manager = GetSystemService(NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                CreateNotificationChannel(Manager);
            }
            
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ExampleBroadcast));
            intent.SetAction("deneme");

            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

            var notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ChannelId)
               .SetContentTitle(Title)
               .SetContentText(Description)
               .SetOngoing(true)
               .SetVisibility(NotificationCompat.VisibilityPublic)
               .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.appicon)
               .AddAction(new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(Resource.Drawable.appicon, "Alarmı Kapat", pendingIntent).Build())
               ; //birden fazla bildirim gönderecek isek bunu alttaki notificationa eklemek lazım not...Build()


            StartForeground(NotificationId, notification.Build());
            
        }
        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            var index = intent.GetIntExtra("alarm", -1);
            Debug.WriteLine("Start: " + index + " " + intent.Action);
            var json = File.ReadAllText(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory + "/alarm.json");
            var alarms = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Alarm>>(json);
            var alarm = alarms[index];
            Title = alarm.AlarmName;
            Description = $"{0}m sonra alarm çalacak!";


            mediaPlayer.SetDataSource(alarm.SoundPath);
            mediaPlayer.Prepare();
            mediaPlayer.Start();
            timer.Start();
            StartForegroundService();
            
            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        public override bool StopService(Intent intent)
        {
            base.StopService(intent);
            Debug.WriteLine("Stop Service: ");
            mediaPlayer.Stop();
            Vibration.Default.Cancel();
            timer.Stop();
            return true;
        }

        private void VibrateTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Vibration.Default.Vibrate(2000);
        }
        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();
            if (token != null)
            {
                token.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                token.Cancel();
            }
            
        }


    }
    
}
```

Broadcast code:

```
using Android.Content;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WakeUp.Platforms.Android
{
    [BroadcastReceiver]
    internal class ExampleBroadcast: BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if(intent.Action == "deneme")
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(intent.Action);
                Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(LocationService));
                Debug.WriteLine(context.ToString());
                context.StopService(serviceIntent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the broadcast code works (when the button in the notification is pressed) the notification closes, but the code part in the StopService method that I override in the service class does not work. Where am I doing wrong?

The service is working, player and vibration are fine. There seems to be a problem only in the StopService part.

Comment: You can try the code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> the notification closes, but the code part in the StopService method that I override in the service class does not work.

`notification closes` means the service has been stopped. But the `StopService` method you override has not been called when you call the `context.StopService(serviceIntent)`.

So you can use another way to stop the service without the BroadcastReceiver:

```
namespace WakeUp.Platforms.Android
{
    [Service]
    internal class LocationService : Service
    {
        .......
        public void StartForegroundService()
        {
            ......
            
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(LocationService));
            intent.SetAction("deneme");

            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

           ......
        }
        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            if(intent?.Action == "deneme")
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Stop Service: ");
                mediaPlayer.Stop();
                Vibration.Default.Cancel();
                timer.Stop();
                this.StopSelf();
            }
            ......
        }


       ......
    }
    
}
```

I changed the code above based on yours and it will call the code in the `if(intent?.Action == "deneme")` when the button in the notification is pressed.